# Writing css selector for the pages tab in Facebook for selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to point my chrome driver to the right css locator in order to narrow down the search to just facebook pages. Inspect element yields the following html code
[image]

I thought I'd write the selector on my own so I did the following

````
wait = WebDriverWait(f.browser, 10)
pages = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='d2edcug0 hpfvmrgz qv66sw1b c1et5uql lr9zc1uh jq4qci2q a3bd9o3v ekzkrbhg oo9gr5id']")))
pages.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        ```
That clearly doesn't work, though. (update: upon testing, it didn't work :( )
````

Comment: Where can I find that element in facebook ?

Comment: bar on the right, for search results

Comment: okay, I figured that out, you might wanna check out the below solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not the below xpath  :

```
//span[text()='Pages']
```

?

In code it would be something like this  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(f.browser, 10)
pages = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Pages']")))
pages.click()
```

or if you are very keen to use css,

```
a[href^='https://www.facebook.com/pages/'] span
```

should work for you.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(f.browser, 10)
pages = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href^='https://www.facebook.com/pages/'] span")))
pages.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, for either solutions the output is an error of non interactable element.

Comment: Are you launching browser in full screen mode ? if not you can launch the broswer in full screen using `driver.maximize_window()` you can write this line where you have driver.get()